# Docker says "error 28 from storage engine"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

this morning everything worked fine, since a few hours I get this response from my database docker container, when I start my Docker containers:

```
db_1      | ERROR: 1030  Got error 28 from storage engine
db_1      | 180129 13:57:08 [ERROR] Aborting
db_1      |
db_1      | 180129 13:57:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
db_1      |
re53rc1_db_1 exited with code 1
```

I googled this and found out, that it means there is not enough disk space available. My `df -h` on my docker apache container shows me this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none             60G   57G     0 100% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2        60G   57G     0 100% /var/www
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
osxfs           465G  425G   41G  92% /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/firmware
```

I am wondering why this comes up so suddenly and how can I fix this? My hdd has > 40GB of space, so this can not be the reason.

Thanks.

Comment: is the second output your machine output or the output from the docker container?

Comment: @edwin the Output from the apache docker container.

Comment: and do you have another container with your db? or did you installed the mysql on this container?

Comment: I have another container with my DB, but this container does not start due to the reason above.

Comment: maybe you can check the storage on that container as well, because the error has to do with mysql

Comment: Hm, I would but "docker ps" does not show me that database container, so I have no chance to access it. It tells me: 53rc1_db_1 exited with code 1

Comment: What storage driver are you using? `docker info  -f '{{ .Driver }}'` Show the disk usage on your host rather than inside the container. Both `df -h` and `df -i`. Show the definition for the db container, including the image and any volumes. As an aside, docker did not output the above error message, the application (mysql) did and docker passed it along.

Comment: what @BMitch said plus you may try to stop all other containers and start only the db (if you don't have any dependencies) and see if then works

Comment: I cleaned my system and removed unused images/volumes. Now I get another error: EXCEPTION: #<Docker::Compose::Error: 'up' failed with status 'pid 8967 exit 1': An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.> I use the aufs driver.

Comment: It is working now.